# Does this approach of performing predictive modeling make sense?

Tags: forecasting, error

My company purchased software for forecasting orders.  The software looks at all locations where a particular order came from and adds up all the location demands in each month.  It then builds a forecasting model for this aggregate by determining the MSE of several models, e.g., SES, Holt, MA, etc. and picking the model with the smallest error.  It then takes this "Optimum" model and applies it to the data at each location, i.e., the disaggregate.  To me this doesn't make sense, but I lack the statistical reasoning to take my concerns forward.

Comment: Could you clarify whether this model selection occurred just once, occurs monthly, occurs separately at each location, or monthly at each location?

Comment: It occurs in a rolling horizon window with h=1.  For example, Jan-16 to Dec-16 is used to forecast for Jan-17.  Next month, Feb-16-Jan-17 is used to forecast for Feb-17, etc.  The model selection will occur monthly within the rolling window.  Whatever method is chosen for the aggregate is then applied to each location in each month.